# Ненейтральные субъективные суждения в списках книг и учебных ресурсов

Tags: обсуждение, учебные-материалы

### Вопрос

Удалять ли ненейтральные субъективные характеристики к книгам и учебным материалам?

---

---

### Примеры

[**Список материалов по Linux**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/582545/1) по крайней мере на момент написания данного вопроса содержал выражения «лучшее», «отличный», «очень крутой», «очень неплохой», «превосходный». Вероятно, они подлежат удалению.

Также недавно я [**отредактировал**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/420126/revisions) правку модератора, содержащую оценочные суждения в адрес книги по Python.

---

---

### Аргументы за удаление (добавляйте, если есть ещё)

1. Сколько людей, столько и мнений. Кому-то превосходная книга может показаться отвратительной, равно как и наоборот. Разногласия могут возникать и у профессионалов. Почему на Stack Overflow должна выноситься одна точка зрения, а не противоположная.
2. Даже специалисты могут не знать всей выходящей литературы, особенно если тема обширная, чтобы определить из всей литературы лучшую. И есть эффект: «по какой книге изучал, ту и советуешь».
3. Возможные аффилированность, конфликт интересов.
4. Списки материалов поддерживаются сообществом, откровенно плохие книги и учебные ресурсы туда не попадут.

---

---

### Аргументы против удаления (добавляйте, если есть ещё)

Как ни крути, знак равенства между всеми учебными материалами ставить нельзя. Одни книги лучше усваиваются, излагают материал, понятнее, интереснее других. Если только приводить сухие факты, пользователь может выбрать из списка равных худшую книгу и потеряет время/будет испытывать недостаток навыков.

Comment: Пожалуйста, вынесите аргументы «за» и «против» в соответствующие ответы, чтобы сообщество могло проголосовать. Было бы здорово, назначить их общими, чтобы все участники могли дополнять их.

Comment: Кстати фраза "Эта книга хороша как учебник" была не про то, что книга *хороша*, а про то что она подходит для использования в качестве учебника (а не, например, справочника).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, придерживаюсь точки зрения, что сначала необходимо дать высказаться; когда же аргументы в комментариях будут исчерпаны, тогда и открывать голосование. // 1. В моих аргументах что-то будет неучтено, возможно, у других пользователей другие идеи и мнения по данному вопросу. // 2. У одного варианта могут быть сильные, у другого более слабые для публики аргументы. Часто бывает, что к «слабому» варианту впоследствии будут добавлены дополнительные аргументы, но плюсы/минусы уже выставлены, и на эти уже выставленные оценки будут ориентироваться пользователи. Спасибо.

Comment: @Nofate, да, я понял. Удалил фразу потому что, на мой взгляд, `хороша` — ненейтральный эпитет, в отличие от, например, `данная книга по формату является учебником, а не справочником`. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, заодно, чем не угодили две ссылки на стёпик?

Comment: @Nofate, [**выполнял решение сообщества**](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3413/199934). Не понял, почему там комментарии не отобразились. Вероятно, не вместились. Спасибо.

Comment: "Видеолекции, задачи на программирование (Python)" это не совсем то же, что просто видеокурсы с ютуба. На курсере есть курс по алгоритмам, который ведёт сам Седжвик. Там тоже видео, но это курс по книге. https://www.coursera.org/learn/introduction-to-algorithms

Comment: Степик это все же MOOС с задачками, а не видеокурс.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ответьте только на поставленный вопрос: является ли `Python: основы и применение` с сайта Stepik.org «видеокурсом»? Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных есть дух закона, а есть буква. Нет, не является, это MOOC.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, пожалуй, Вы правы. `{Видеокурсы}` ∉ `{МООС}`. Спасибо.

Comment: Ничего удалять не надо. Если у Вас есть свое мнение, напишите его. Если написать нечего, то очевидно, что и Ваша оценка ничего не стоит. Просто пройдите мимо.

Comment: @avp, каждый может написать своё мнение?

Comment: @СашаЧерных, думаю, писать должен тот, кто знаком с той или иной литературой. Такой человек должен обладать знаниями об этой литературе, а также иметь опыт в той области, о которой говорится в этой литературе. К сожалению, этого никак не проверить, поэтому придётся полагаться исключительно на честность респондента, а также опыт тех членов сообщества ruSO, которые отслеживают топики с литературой. Приношу извинения что слегка сумбурно изложил мысль.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, да, каждый (и по поводу вопроса и по поводу других ответов).